# how to unzip an image in the iphone code

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, nsurlconnection

to unzip an image file sent after gzipping it on the server side i know i have to use gzopen.

i want to know if there is a more direct and simple way to do this with 'compressiontype' or something related that once i have the 'zipped image data' received from the server using NSURLconnection can i load an imageview using an easier method.

Answer (score 0):

The zip library you are using will dictate how you can unzip the received data.

I haven't found a zip library that will unzip directly from an NSData object; I've found that the data needs to be written to a file (in the documents directory) and then unzipped.

I use 'ziparchive' available http://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/wiki/PageName